# how to add gradient transition to my image (not background) on hover using tailwind

Tags: css, user-interface, hover, tailwind-css

i want to put gradient color of #323232 (0% on the top and 90% on the bottom) on IMAGE hover but instead i only changed its bg. i tried to change the opacity & change the color but it's still a solid color not gradient.

this is my code

```
<Layout>
      <Container>
        <div className="grid grid-cols-3 px-{100}">
          {gallery.map((el, i) => {
            return (
              <img className="transition duration-500 transition-all hover:bg-primary-hover hover:opacity-10 delay-100" src={gallery[i].imgSrc} />
            )
          })}
        </div>
      </Container>
    </Layout>
```

this is how i wanted it to be:
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ewyy.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the image hover by placing a div below the image and applying the gradient to this div, then on hovering the image, you can change the opacity of image.

I had put black and white color, however you use your choice of colour.

Below is the code,

```html
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

    <div class="relative mix-blend-overlay">
      <img src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back05.jpg" alt="BannerImage" class="absolute h-[70vh] lg:h-[80vh] w-full object-cover object-right hover:opacity-50 " />
      <div class="absolute -z-10 bg-gradient-to-t from-white via-gray-900 to-black h-[70vh] lg:h-[80vh] w-full" />

    </div>
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! Now I got the idea of what to do and moving to the next error:fitting the gradient to the loop of images.

Comment: I had answered what you asked, please accept my answer. For next error, raise another question